# What does "function declarations at the top level" mean?

Tags: javascript

In [this JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), it says:

> var statements and function declarations at the top level create
> properties of the global object. On the other hand, let and const
> declarations never create properties of the global object.

What does "function declarations at the top level" mean? does it mean functions that are not inner functions?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Top level means not inside other functions or objects or classes or closures. <del>Where `this` refers to the `window` object.</del>

```js
console.log(this === window)    // true
var x = 5

function foo() {
  console.log(this === window)    // true
  var y = 3
}

foo.call(this);

console.log(y)    // not defined
```

Comment: Well `this` can refer to the global object for other reasons.

Comment: Then it is top level in a way?

Comment: No. If you call any function, even one nested inside 5 layers of other functions, the `this` value may be the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode) if the function call is made with no context, like just a "naked" function call. It's still not top-level however, and clearly its declaration will not create a property of the global object.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct however.

Comment: So how can you know if you are at the top level?

Comment: It's a lexical thing; in other words, if you look at a source file, anything declared outside another function is top-level. However, as the quote in the OP notes, even then `const` and `let` do not create global-object properties.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "function declarations at the top level" mean? Does it mean functions that are not inner functions?

Yes, it means just that. It refers to the syntax of the declarations: anything that is not nested inside some other syntactical structure.

However, the statement is not quite accurate. It should be restricted to the "top level *of scripts*", since `var` and `function` declarations at the top level of module code don't create global variables - they declare variables in the global scope. Also, `var` declarations in blocks (`{ … }`) still declare global variables (that become properties of the global object) as long as they're not nested in a function.